# Codeigniter Project in live server always gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I've trying to solve this issue for the past 24 hrs but nothing seems to work. It works fine on my local with the following htaccess code.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ocr/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I copy my project into /ocr dir of public_html dir in the server with the same htaccess code it gives 500 Internal Server Error. 
Can anyone help me fix this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

P.S to moderators. Please don't flag this as duplicate question as I tried almost all answers found here regarding this issue and none worked.

Comment: 500 can mean so many things, we have to find out what the error is. Please follow this: https://imgur.com/a/VnOFNwt

Answer (score 0):

Uff.. took the hell out of me to fix this issue. Spent more than 48 hrs trying random stuffs with .htaccess files. There were no error log files generated inside application/logs dir. So, that gave me a massive headache.

But finally from somewhere it hit my head that I should see the error log files from cpanel and it was where I found whats causing the issue. My project dir had 777 permission and that was the reason. Then it worked when I changed the dir permission to 755.